# integrated report in ireport with jsf

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

hallo all..
i have a problem to create pdf format report with jasper report/ireport plugin in jsf ?
i've made a report in jasper report, but i can't integrate it with jsf for create pdf format..
thank for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could could do it this way. Add a `h:commandLink` on a page pointing to an action method of your bean:

```
<h:commandLink value="download report" action="#{myBean.downloadReport}" />
```

In your bean you should generate your report and write it to the `OutputStream` of the response:

```
public class MyBean {

  public String downloadReport() {

    // get HttpServletResponse
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = 
      (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    // set correct content type
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    // get OutputStream
    OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();

    // TODO: generate PDF and write the report to this output stream 

    // mark response as completed
    context.responseComplete();
    return null;

  }
}
```

Comment: owh i undurstand it's simple code. thank's.. but, i do acces the database in my report..     in this report I have to send a variable that will be accessing certain data in the database.     how do I add a variable (parameter in ireport) into my report via the form JSF?

Comment: I'm not a real expert on Jasper Reports. You should take a deeper look at their API. Perhaps this example helps: http://seamframework.org/61907.lace

Comment: thank you very much.. it's very helpul..